# Create vector using for loop with if else condition

Tags: r

How can I turn the 3 item output of the for loop below into a data frame. In attempting a solution, I've tried:

-Creating an object related to the for loop, but couldn't succeed
-Creating a matrix, to no effect

What code would turn the output into a vector or list?

```
> for(i in X$Planned)ifelse(is.na(i),print("ISNA"),print("NOTNA"))
[1] "NOTNA"
[1] "NOTNA"
[1] "ISNA"
```

Comment: Can you make your problem [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and share `dput(X$Planned)`?

Comment: why not `X$IsNA <- ifelse(is.na(X$Planned), "ISNA", "NOTNA")`

Comment: I appreciate your support r2evans, this solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sapply(x$Planned, function(elem) if (is.na(elem)) {"isNA"} else {"notNA"})

# this will do it!

# however, it will be slower than the vectorized form

ifelse(is.na(x$Planned), "isNA", "notNA")
```